# Using Python Class to make game- how to update self init?

Tags: python

I am making a text-based game on python using the class system to keep track of main character changes (like its name). I am writing the main code for the game outside of the Main Character Class- inside of the main function.

I am struggling because I need to update self.character_name inside the Main Character class to an input from the user inside the main function. I am unsure how to do this, I have the code written below- however it is not updating the name inside Main Character class. How can I rewrite this?

I'm also worried that I will have this problem when trying to update pets, characters_known. However, I do not seem to have this problem with updating Health or XP....

```
class Main_Character():

def __init__(self):
    self.health=100
    self.exp=0    
    self.level=0
    self.character_name=""
    self.characters_known={None}
    self.pets={None}
    self.progression_tracker=0

def __str__(self):
    return "Name: "+ str(self.character_name)+"  |  "+ "Health:"+ str(self.health) + "  |  " +"XP:"+ str(self.exp) + "  |  "+ "Level:"+ str(self.level)+"  |  "+"Pets:"+str(self.pets)

def Char_Name(self,name):
    if name.isalpha()==False:
        print("You entered a name containing non-alphabetic characters, pease reenter a new name:")
        main()
    elif len(name)>=10:
        print("You entered a name containing 10 or more characters, pease reenter a new name:")
        main()
    else:
        self.character_name=name


def Char_Level_Experience(self,exp,b):
    self.exp+=exp
    b=2
    if exp<=0:
        exp=1
    ans = 1
    level=0
    while ans<exp:
        ans *= b
        level += 1
    if ans == exp:
        self.level=level
        print("You have reached level", self.level)
    else:
        level = int(log(exp, 2))
        level = min(level, exp) 
        if level>=0:
            self.level=level
        else:
            level=0


def healing(self,heal):
    if self.health+heal>=100:
        self.health=100
    else:
        self.health+=heal


def other_answers(answer):
    if answer=='quit':
        raise SystemExit
    if answer=='pets':
        print("Pets owned:", Main_Character().pets)
        user_decision=input("Would you like to continue where you left off?    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to go back to main menu")
        if user_decision=='yes':
            if Main_Character().progression_tracker==0:
                main()
            elif Main_Character().progression_tracker==1:
                choice1()
        if user_decision=='no':
                main()
        else:
            other_answers(user_decision)
    if answer=='characters':
        print("Characters met:", Main_Character().characters_known)
        user_decision=input("Would you like to continue where you left off? Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to go back to main menu:")
        if user_decision=='yes':
            if Main_Character().progression_tracker==0:
                main()
            if Main_Character().progression_tracker==1:
                choice1()
        if user_decision=='no':
                main()
        else:
            other_answers(user_decision)

def start_check():
    print("If you understand the game, type 'go' to continue- if not, type 'more information' to receive more information about how to play the game")
    begin_game=input("")
    if begin_game=="go":
        choice1()
    if begin_game=='more information':
        print("\n","The object of the game is to gain XP [experience points] without dying")
        start_check()
    else:
        other_answers(begin_game)

def choice1():
    Main_Character().progression_tracker=1
    print("You are a knight in the Kings Guard- the King has asked to meet with you about a very special mission")
    print("What would you like to do?")
    print("  1.Go Directly to King","\n", "2. Finish your dinner")
    choice=input("1 or 2?")
    if choice=="1":
        Main_Character().Char_Level_Experience(1,2)
    elif choice=="2":
        Main_Character().Char_Level_Experience(.5,2)
    else:
        other_answers(choice)
    print(Main_Character())

def main(): 
    print("Welcome!")
    unfiltered_name=input("Please enter the name of your character:")
    Main_Character().Char_Name(unfiltered_name)
    print("Welcome,", Main_Character().character_name,"!", "Here are your current stats!")
    print(Main_Character())
    start_check()
```

Comment: Generally, keep the code examples as minimal as possible. For Python, double check the indentation when posting (in this question it is clearly wrong). Also, make sure the lines are short (less than 80 characters) and follow the standard style (this last one is a "plus")

Answer (score 2):

You haven't quite understood how classes and instances work.

Calling the class is what you do when you need a new character. Every time you call `Main_Character()`, you get a whole new instance - with the default values as set in `__init__`. If you had characters for each of your friends, you would call it *one* time for each one. You then would need to keep each of those instances in a variable, so you can reference them again each time.

So, for instance:

```
my_character = Main_Character()
unfiltered_name=input("Please enter the name of your character:")
my_character.Char_Name(unfiltered_name)
print("Welcome,", my_character.character_name,"!", "Here are your current stats!")
print(my_character)
```

Comment: and this is not only one problem. He trying to call main() from inside of class methods. Hidden recursion ;))

Comment: I understand, however, when I do this the updated name will only work inside the Main function instead of throughout all of the functions I will have for each choice the character may make.

Comment: Yes. You need to pass that variable around. Or, you may want to rethink the structure of your program and make the functions into methods on the class itself; then everything is in one place, which is the whole point of encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

You create a *new* character each time you call `Main_Character`. Instead, you should call it once:

```
the_character = Main_Character()
...
the_character.name = "..."
```